# IE 7 & 8 (gradient + Border-radius)

Tags: internet-explorer, border, gradient, css

I want to do gradient + Border-radius and in all browsers, but in IE 7 and 8 not, I tried to use PIE but it dosen't support rgba (alpha) and I decided to use filter and grandient works, but overlaps Border-radius.
I hope you help me :)

Answer (score 0):

use jquery UI.it will be help for you 
http://jqueryui.com/

or

This link useful for you http://border-radius.com/

put all corner value in the textboxes and copy the css value

Comment: Hello,
It is my code: http://wklej.org/id/694564/
PIE probably use jQuery so I don't if it help